# How to avoid timeouts in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, timeout

I use `netNamedPipeBinding`, and my service methods return nothing (`void`), but they timeout:

> TimeoutException: "The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout."
>
> Server stack trace: 
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

To avoid this I turned my service into a `OneWay` operation. But the timeout still occurs. I expected that it solved my problem. Its the netMsmqBinding the only one that could avoid such timeout?

I also tried to make all processing in a separate thread, so the service can disconnect earlier, with no success.

Comment: I had so many timeout issues with WCF, amongst other things. So I decided to switch back to asmx. You could perhaps start by upgrading to .net 4. I've heard there are many WCF improvements, if you've got the stomach for it.

Comment: @JL WCF is working fine for me. The issue here was that I had so many connections that no service could handle it. So I modified the clients to reduce the number of calls.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7898696/1203182 related solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel it is a connection timeout. So the binding should not play a role in it. It might be that there is some issue for the service to accept the invocation. How have you deployed them or is there any issue on the server side? Can you do some logging or tracing? The tracelistener can be turned on probably.

Comment: The issue here was that I had so many connections that no service could handle it. So I modified the clients to reduce the number of calls.

Comment: If no of connections increase and if the network can bear it, you can use Throttling to take care of maximum concurrent instances and to keep the rest in a queue.