# IIS Maximum Concurrent Connections

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have a .Net project and I want to changed the maximum concurrent connections with cmd or exe in IIS default website.

How can I changed it with script, exe or cmd commant?

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7898696/888617 you can edit your machine.config to set the max connections.

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="65535"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

You can get the config file with:

```
string configPath =  System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.SystemConfigurationFile;
```