# IIS Connection Limit in W8.1 32 bit

Tags: iis, signalr, windows-8.1

I am using one of those PC on a USB stick.

it comes pre-installed with Windows 8.1 32bit.

I have IIS installed on it.

I have my web app installed using asp.net and SignalR.

There seems to be a connection limit because as soon as I open another tab/browser the connecting status of the 2nd SignalR keeps on saying 'connecting.

Can anyone confirm whether this is because the number of concurrent connections to my IIS web site is just 1 and if so what options do I have to make it to support many client connections?

Any solution or alternative technologies I could utilise?

I admit W8.1 32 bit is not the most common OS to use and hence the lack of searchable material on the web.

Thanks

Comment: Does anything discussed in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849884/what-is-limiting-the-of-simultaneous-connections-my-asp-net-application-can-ma) help?

Comment: Hi, possibly. I will go through it All when back at PC. Thanks